# Spaces under Flexible Height Gallery Rows

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

**Considerations**:

- I'm using nested Gallery Controls to create a Collapsible Navigation menu. My first Gallery control is a Flexible Height Gallery and for each of its row, I've a Vertical gallery control for it.
- I'm also using a 1923*1080 (width*height) Custom Screen Size for my application. (as shown in the screenshot below)

[image]

**Issue that i'm running into**:

My collapsable nav looks fine in the EDIT mode of the application (as shown in the screenshot below)

[image]

but when i simply click on the application name to view the app in NON-EDIT Mode (not sure if this is the right term for it), i see blank empty spaces under each flexible height gallery row (as shown in the screenshot below). I'm guessing the stretched out screen res (1923*1080) for Non-Edit mode of the app could be causing that.

[image]

My **question** is: how do we fix it? (Given that the Flexible Height Gallery Control adjusts its row height as per its content). I've also noticed that the lenth of extra space (under each row) depends on the number of items in its nested vertical gallery control. If there are more items in the nested gallery, there's more space underneath it. Any thoughts?

**Attribute values for my Flexible Height Gallery**:

- **Height**: 1080
- **Template Size**: 65 (The spaces aren't affected if i try to change this)
- **Template Padding**: 4

**Attribute values for my Nested Vertical Gallery**:

- **Height**: CountRows(ThisItem.NavSubItems)*NestedGallery.TemplateHeight
- **Template Size**: 50
- **Template Padding**: 0

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem can be resolved by setting the Y value of the nested galleries to the negative height of the preceding gallery.